# IBM MQ Send message

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am able to send the message through the Java Test class. Able to see the string message in the console. But while updating it in log, I am getting a null response. I am getting this error "Invalid Demand Code". Can anyone help me with this?

And can anyone suggest me how to convert from `JMSTextMessage` to `JMSBytesMessage`

IBM MQ Send Bytes message through Java Test Class.

Any help would be helpful

```
      MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
      cf.setHostName("");
      cf.setPort();
      cf.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);
      cf.setQueueManager("");
      cf.setChannel("");

      MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();
      MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("");
      MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);

      long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;

      JMSTextMessage message = (JMSTextMessage) session.createTextMessage("B+VCTR||*RPI/LAX/8548|16MAR+B+"); 

      connection.start();

      System.out.println("before Sent message:\\n" + message);

      sender.send(message);
      System.out.println("Sent message:\\n" + message);

      sender.close();
      session.close();
      connection.close();

      System.out.println("\\nSUCCESS\\n");
    }
    catch (JMSException jmsex) {
      System.out.println(jmsex);
      System.out.println("\\nFAILURE2\\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println(ex);
      System.out.println("\\nFAILURE1\\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following two methods demonstrate how to pass UTF-8 encoded text in BytesMessage:

```
Message createBytesMessage(Session session, String text) throws JMSException {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8"); 
    byte[] data = text.getBytes(charset);

    BytesMessage bmsg = session.createBytesMessage();
    bmsg.writeBytes(data);
    return bmsg;
}

String readBytesMessage(BytesMessage bmsg) throws JMSException {
    int len = (int) bmsg.getBodyLength();
    byte[] data = new byte[len];
    bmsg.readBytes(data);

    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    String text = new String(data, charset);
    return text;
}
```

Essentially a BytesMessage is used to send a byte array. To pass a text using BytesMessages start with converting text to bytes. Here I have used UTF-8 encoding to encode text. Any other will do; just use the same charset for reading and writing. You can even parametrize charset by sending charset name as string property of message (the same idea as HTTP charset parameter).

When dealing with TextMessages, IBM MQ will **implicitly do message conversion and encoding.** Most of the time this is undesired behavior as it will not treat unicode characters well. Rules of this conversions are described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032120_.htm). To avoid this behavior use BytesMessages to pass text.

**So how to convert TextMessage to BytesMessage?**

Read text from TextMessage. Than send it as a new BytesMessage.